Abraham and Sarah family line
If Cain and his brothers married their sisters, and Abraham did with his half sister, and more so with the rest of the family lineage, then wouldn't everyone else who was born from that family line be relatives? How could it be possible for anyone to marry and have kids with someone who they weren't related too?

Social ethics evolve over time. What is forbidden today, such as close-relative marriages, was not considered unethical in ancient times. Science plays a crucial role in these legalizations, as it has been discovered that genetic disorders are highly likely in closely related individuals due to their similar DNA, leading to health problems for their offspring.
According to the account of creation in Genesis, everything God created was good (Genesis 1:31), meaning there were no genetic concern for close-relative marriages initially. However, when Adam and Eve sinned and were expelled from Eden (Genesis 3:24), humanity had to work to survive. Over time, genetic mutations occurred, leading to current understandings.
Our genes confirm that all humans are related, but close-relatives are defined according to cultural practices. Siblings have a direct impact, while cousins already reduce genetic similarity by half. The risk of genetic disorders diminishes significantly if partners are not from the direct bloodline.


How could it be possible for anyone to marry and have kids with someone who they weren't related too?

It isn't possible.
But it has nothing to do with Abraham or Cain, or any other religious topic.
You have two parents, four grandparents, eight great-grandparents, etc.
Every generation the number of ancestors doubles.
If a generation is 25 years long:

500 years ago you had 220 ancestors at the same time.
That's over a million people.
a thousand years ago you had 240 ancestors alive at the same time.
That's more than a trillion people.

The first is theoretically possible.
The second is completely ridiculous.
We are all related, multiple times over.
It's a simple mathematical fact.
